# Parsing JSON URL in R with different number of fields

Tags: json, r, parsing, url

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to read some JSON data obtained from a URL in R. I'm able to read in the data, and call on each observation to get the values (as characters which is fine), but I can't seem to find a way to get the data in a table format (basically like in excel).

I've tried to create a loop which calls on each field to place it in an empty matrix, however not every object has the same number of fields (ie. some values have Label1 and Label2, while others just have Label1). I get the error that the subscipts are out of bounds. What I was thinking was to make a conditional statement whereas if the field existed then the value of the field would be put in the data matrix, and if the field does not exist then I would insert an NA. I get a subscript error automatically though and cannot do the conditional evaluation - I've looked to see if I can coerce an error to become an NA, but I don't think this is possible.

I'm starting the index from j=3, since the first two observations in the JSON code are not needed for me. My problem is that for example **"json$poi[[j]]$label[[2]]$value"** may not exist for every observation and I automatically get an error when the code comes across the first observation missing this field.

The data is quite big - around 4480 observations with up to 20 fields each. I only require the 9 fields I have listed however. Here is a link to the data URL - it may take some time to load. Im quite new to coding, and especially trying to deal with JSON files, so my apology if this has a simple solution that I'm not seeing.

Thanks!

http://tourism.citysdk.cm-lisboa.pt/pois/?limit=-1

```
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)

json <- fromJSON(getURL('http://tourism.citysdk.cm-lisboa.pt/pois/?limit=-1'))

ljson <- length(json$poi)-2
data <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=ljson, ncol=9)

for(i in 1:ljson)
{
j <- i+2

d1 <- json$poi[[j]]$location$point[[1]]$Point$posList
d2 <- json$poi[[j]]$label[[1]]$value
d3 <- json$poi[[j]]$label[[2]]$value
d4 <- json$poi[[j]]$category[[1]]$value
d5 <- json$poi[[j]]$category[[2]]$value
d6 <- json$poi[[j]]$id
d7 <- json$poi[[j]]$author$value
d8 <- json$poi[[j]]$license$value
d9 <- json$poi[[j]]$description[[1]]$value

if(exists("d1") == TRUE){
    d1 <- json$poi[[j]]$location$point[[1]]$Point$posList 
} else {
    d1 <- NA 
} 
if(exists("d2") == TRUE){
    d2 <- json$poi[[j]]$label[[1]]$value 
} else {
    d2 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d3") == TRUE){
    d3 <- json$poi[[j]]$label[[2]]$value
} else {
    d3 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d4") == TRUE){
    d4 <- json$poi[[j]]$category[[1]]$value 
} else {
    d4 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d5") == TRUE){
    d5 <- json$poi[[j]]$category[[2]]$value 
} else {
    d5 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d6") == TRUE){
    d6 <- json$poi[[j]]$id 
} else {
    d6 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d7") == TRUE){
    d7 <- json$poi[[j]]$author$value 
} else {
    d7 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d8") == TRUE){
    d8 <- json$poi[[j]]$license$value 
} else {
    d8 <- NA 
}
if(exists("d9") == TRUE){
    d9 <- json$poi[[j]]$description[[1]]$value 
} else {
    d9 <- NA 
}
data[i,] <- rbind(c(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9))    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSON & XML list structures `str` is your friend! You can use that to inspect all or portions of a list structure. `sapply` on individual components to extract is probably better than the `for` construct and you'll need to handle `NULL`s  and missing sub-structure components to build a data frame from that JSON (and many JSON files, actually). The following gets you started, but you still have some work to do:

```
# simplify extraction (saves typing, too)
poi <- json$poi

# start at 3rd element
poi <- poi[3:length(poi)] 

# have to do some special checking since the value isn't always there
poi_points <- sapply(poi, function(x) {
  if ("point" %in% names(x$location) & length(x$location$point) > 0) {
    x$location$point[[1]]$Point$posList
  } else {
    NA
  }
})

# this removes NULLs which the data.frame call won't like later
poi_description <- sapply(poi, function(x) {
  if (is.null(x$description[[1]]$value)) {
    NA
  } else {
    x$description[[1]]$value 
  }
})

# this removes NULLs which the data.frame call won't like later
poi_category <- sapply(poi, function(x) {
  if (is.null(x$category[[1]]$value)) {
    NA
  } else {
    x$category[[1]]$value 
  }
})

# simpler extractions

poi_label <- sapply(poi, function(x) x$label[[1]]$value)
poi_id <- sapply(poi, function(x) x$id)
poi_author <- sapply(poi, function(x) x$author$value)
poi_license <- sapply(poi, function(x) x$license$value)

# make a data frame
poi <- data.frame(poi_label, poi_category, poi_id, poi_points, poi_author, poi_license, poi_description)

str(poi)

## 'data.frame': 4482 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ poi_label      : Factor w/ 4482 levels "\"Bloco das Águas Livres\", edifício de habitação, comércio e serviços",..: 363 765 764 1068 174 419 461 762 420 412 ...
##  $ poi_category   : Factor w/ 129 levels "Acessórios de Uso Pessoal",..: 33 33 33 33 33 33 123 33 33 33 ...
##  $ poi_id         : Factor w/ 4482 levels "52d7bf4d723e8e0b0cc08b69",..: 2 3 4 5 7 8 15 16 17 18 ...
##  $ poi_points     : Factor w/ 3634 levels "38.405892 -9.93503",..: 975 244 478 416 301 541 2936 2975 2850 2830 ...
##  $ poi_author     : Factor w/ 1 level "CitySDK": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ poi_license    : Factor w/ 1 level "open-data": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ poi_description: Factor w/ 2831 levels "","\n","\n\n",..: 96 1051 NA NA 777 1902 NA 1038 81 82 ...
##
```